# youtube api's count does not match number of items retrieved

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api

It appears that youtube's count of playlist items does not match the actual number of items in the playlist. Is there some reason for this or am I doing something wrong?

My code below returns this:

```
there are 1275 videos in the playlist 
we retrieved 1274 videos
```

Code, put your key in to use

```
import requests
import json

key = '' #Put your key here
upload_playlist_id = 'UUG-Et3jfinzlQql4uEYjAVw'

# Get the video count from the content details of the playlist
params = {
    'key' : key,
    'id' : upload_playlist_id,
    'part' : 'contentDetails'
}

response = requests.get(r'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists', params)
data = json.loads(response.text)
video_count = data['items'][0]['contentDetails']['itemCount']
print("there are %s videos in the playlist " % (video_count))

# Get the video count from counting all of the items in the playlist
params = {
    'key' : key,
    'playlistId' : upload_playlist_id,
    'maxResults' : 50,
    'part' : 'id'
}
response = requests.get(r'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems', params)
data_list = [json.loads(response.text)]

while 'nextPageToken' in data_list[-1]:
    params['pageToken'] = data_list[-1]['nextPageToken']
    response = requests.get(r'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems', params)
    data_list.append(json.loads(response.text))

video_count = sum([len(page_data['items']) for page_data in data_list])
print("we retrieved %s videos" % (video_count))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the total count of the video in the `playlistId` that you provide using the [Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), and I get a result of 1275 videos.

Here is the query that I use to get the total number of videos for the `playlistId` **"UUG-Et3jfinzlQql4uEYjAVw"**

Check the `"itemCount"` parameter to check the total number of videos.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=contentDetails&id=UUG-Et3jfinzlQql4uEYjAVw&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: I tried that, the problem is that when you get the items from the playlist - there are 1274 videos. `itemCount` does not match the actual count.

Comment: What do you mean by "when you get the items from the playlist"? Did you mean the YouTube app itself? not the API?